# extract columns and aggregate the values using awk

Tags: awk

I have the following in a flat file test.txt

```
cat test.txt
2017-08-26 15:38:51.4,1.6814,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:51.4,0.53080004,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:51.4,1.7757,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:51.4,0.5666,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,0.465,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,0.4734,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,1.6006,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,0.4886,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,1.6165,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,0.46879998,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,1.5161,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,3.1766,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,1.5461,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,1.5679,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,1.5355,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,0.49389997,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.324,0.50909996,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.325,1.7934,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.325,3.005,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.325,0.6599,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.325,0.5711,DEV,TEST
2017-08-26 15:38:55.325,1.5683999,DEV,TEST
```

I need the following output

```
2017-08-26 15:38:51  4.5528
           15:38:55  23.0402
```

where 15:38:51 is the timestamp with milliseconds clipped off and 4.5528 is the sum of all values corresponding to 15:38:51 timestamp

Same with 15:38:55 is the timestamp with milliseconds clipped off and 23.0402 is the sum of all values corresponding to 15:38:55 timestamp

I tried this awk command

$

```
 awk -F ".," '{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' test.txt

2017-08-26 15:38:51. 4.5528
2017-08-26 15:38:55.32 23.0402
```

but output is not as expected.

It should instead display date once in the first column
Second column should have corresponding timestamp to the date with milliseconds clipped off and sum of all corresponding values under the timestamp in 3rd column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:],]' '{ a[$1, substr($2,1,index($2,".")-1)]+= $3 }
     END{ for(k in a) { 
          split(k, keys, SUBSEP); 
          printf "%-10s %s %s\n",(!i++? keys[1]:""), keys[2], a[k] } 
     }' file
```

- `-F'[[:space:],]'` - compound field separator
- `substr($2,1,index($2,".")-1)` - truncating the ending part of the *time* value after `.` (i.e. `15:38:55.325` becomes `15:38:55`)
- `a[$1, substr($2,1,index($2,".")-1)]+= $3` - aggregating values for each *date-time* sequence
- `split(k, keys, SUBSEP)` - split the sequence of indices by separator
- `(!i++? keys[1]:"")` - print date value only on 1st line in the 1st field

---

The output:

```
2017-08-26 15:38:51 4.5545
           15:38:55 23.0559
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following `awk` script:

*program.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    OFS=" "
}
{
    sub(/\..*$/,"",$1)
    split($1,dt," ")
    d=dt[1]
    t=dt[2]
    if(!prv_t) {
        prv_t = t
    }

    if(d!=prv_d) {
        prv_d = d
        f = 1
    }

    if(t!=prv_t) {
        if(f) {
            print prv_d,prv_t,s
            f = 0
        } else {
            print "              ",prv_t,s
        }
        prv_t = t
        s = 0
    }
    s+=$2
}

END {
    if(f) {
        print prv_d,prv_t,s
        f = 0
    } else {
        print "          ",prv_t,s
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -f program.awk input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

try following awk too once and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F'[ .,]' '
{
  a[$1,$2]+=$4"."$5
}
END{
  for(i in a){
     split(i, check," ");
     if(check[1]==prev){
        print "\t  ",check[2],a[i]
}
     else{
        print i,a[i]
};
     prev=check[1]
}
}
' SUBSEP=" "   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2017-08-26 15:38:51 4.5545
           15:38:55 23.0559
```